# Error building custome chain spec after adding the node authorization configurations to chain_spec.rs

Tags: substrate-node-template

```bash
Error: Service(Other("Error parsing spec file: missing field `nodeAuthorization` at line 89 column 5"))
```

This is the error message I encounter when trying to build a raw chain spec json file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you follow this tutorial https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/permissioned-network/

I think you should check your chain spec configuration in `fn testnet_genesis`

and check this

```
 node_authorization: NodeAuthorizationConfig {
   nodes: vec![
     (
       OpaquePeerId(bs58::decode("12D3KooWBmAwcd4PJNJvfV89HwE48nwkRmAgo8Vy3uQEyNNHBox2").into_vec().unwrap()),
       endowed_accounts[0].clone()
     ),
     (
       OpaquePeerId(bs58::decode("12D3KooWQYV9dGMFoRzNStwpXztXaBUjtPqi6aU76ZgUriHhKust").into_vec().unwrap()),
       endowed_accounts[1].clone()
     ),
   ],
 },
```

Last but not least, you should give us more details